# Is the term "tribal knowledge" considered culturally insensitive?

Tags: cultural-sensitivity

This term is common in English-speaking workplaces. I'm not sure if there is an equivalent term in other languages. Given the derivation of the term itself, is this term entering the realm of cultural insensitivity or "appropriation"? I've never witnessed anyone get offended at its usage, but I have witnessed offense to other terms of similar derivation.

Comment: I have never been able to raise a single eyebrow, until I read that "tribal knowledge" is a term "common in English-speaking workplaces".

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a language question that is not workplace-specific.

Comment: My only language is English and I have not heard this term used in any workplace.

Comment: Your question *may* be on-topic on [english.se]

Comment: @Lilienthal: feel free to migrate it, however, my question does apply to its usage in the workplace.

Comment: @pay: My experiences with it have been in the IT industry where I've heard it used in every company I've worked, and often. I also experienced this term while in military 20 years ago.

Comment: I'm not sure pointing to a Wikipedia article existing suggests what you think it does, but yes, *of course* there's a Wikipedia article... Interestingly enough though, the Wikipedia page for "Six Sigma" makes no mention of "tribal knowledge", nor do any of the other articles I checked. Either way if you have to ask this question at all it should suggest to you that it probably isn't a generally appropriate workplace term. If it were you wouldn't need to ask.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46759/discussion-between-joel-etherton-and-pay).

Comment: Context is going to be the deciding factor here.

Comment: I've never heard the phrase (English, worked in IT for 25 years) so it cannot be common. What does it mean? Knowledge that is common or universal to members of a tribe but not to outsiders?

Answer (score 3):

> Is the term “tribal knowledge” considered culturally insensitive?

No it's not, it has nothing to do with an actual tribe of any sort, nor does it apply to any particular culture, creed, race, skin colour, sexual orientation or group. It's a word for a particular sort of information rather than denoting a sort of person.

However you do get individuals who with a lot of effort and thought manage to get offended at almost anything. These people might manage to convince themselves that it is both culturally insensitive and extremely offensive and be horrified if you used it in front of them.

Comment: Many things have nothing to do with a specific tribe or particular culture but are deemed offensive. I'm less concerned with what one individual might consider offensive (who can predict that), but rather from those who are familiar with the HR side of the world where "offensive" is a more concrete concept.

Comment: That's my first sentence, the second sentence is because HR is made up of individuals of varying levels of professionalism. In mainstream terms, it's not culturally offensive.

Comment: We use the word palaver in English which is not deemed culturally insensitive, yet in fact it's extremely derogatory and badly misused considering the real meaning in the original language. So it would take a real stretch of the imagination to find 'tribal knowledge' offensive in any way.

Comment: I've not heard this word before. Thanks for pointing me to it.